# How to return a custom error from Fastify v3?

Tags: fastify, custom-errors, custom-error-handling

as you know the default error interface in Fastify looks like

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Missing property blah-blah"
}
```

I really would like to be able to throw back something like

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Missing property blah-blah",
    "myCustomError": "yo yo I am custom"
}
```

I tried multiple (really a lot!) combinations of using the `setErrorHandler` and `addHook("onError")` and I cannot return any custom error.
No matter what I do, the custom errors I throw from inside my handlers are somehow converted to this default interface and can't see to find a way around it. I also tried using the `onSend` and `onResponse` hooks, too. Nothing I tried worked out. :(

Is it even possible to return custom errors in Fastify v3?
If not possible in v3, what about Fastify v4?
Can anybody be so good to provide a code design which enables custom errors in Fastify?

Comment: How do you trigger your `myCustomError`?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon I don't understand what you mean exactly... `myCustomError` is intended to be an extra property of the Error object returned to the caller. That is exactly the thing I want to attach right next to the other three but cannot seem to find a way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

Whenever you return/throw an `Error`, Fastify handles it with the default serializer that does not contain any additional properties.

To do so, you need to list the fields you want as output:

```js
const statusCodes = require('http').STATUS_CODES
const fastify = require('fastify')({ logger: true })

fastify.get('/', async (request, reply) => {
  const err = new Error('hello')
  err.statusCode = 400
  err.myCustomError = 'yo yo I am custom'
  throw err
})

fastify.setErrorHandler(function (error, request, reply) {
  if (error.myCustomError) {
    reply
      .status(error.statusCode || 500)
      .send({
        error: statusCodes[error.statusCode || 500],
        message: error.message,
        myCustomError: error.myCustomError,
        statusCode: error.statusCode || 500
      })
  } else {
    reply.send(error) // fallback to the default serializer
  }
})

// {"error":"Bad Request","message":"hello","myCustomError":"yo yo I am custom","statusCode":400}
fastify.inject('/').then(res => console.log(res.payload))
```

This code works for fastify v3 and v4

Consider to read [this article](https://dev.to/eomm/fastify-error-handlers-53ol) too

Answer (score 1):

To return a validation error with a custom message in `fastify` you can use the `ajv` and `ajv-errors` packages.

```js
import { fastify } from "fastify";
import Ajv from "ajv";
import AjvErrors from "ajv-errors";

const app = fastify();
const ajv = new Ajv({ allErrors: true });
AjvErrors(ajv);

async function createUser(req, reply) {
// create user logic
}

const createUserSchema = {
 body: {
        type: "object",
        required: ["name"],
        properties: {
            name: {
                type: "string",
            },
        },
        additionalProperties: false,
        errorMessage: {
            required: {
                name: "Please provide required name parameter",
            },
        },
    },
};

app.route({
  method: "POST",
  url: "/user",
  schema: createUserSchema,
  handler: createUser,
  validatorCompiler: ({ schema }) => ajv.compile(schema),
  schemaErrorFormatter: (errors) => new Error(errors[0].message),
});
```

With the `schemaErrorFormatter()` property, we specify the custom error formatter. Without this `fastify` by default adds at the beginning of your custom message the place name where the error happened, like `body`, `querystring`, etc. [Example](https://github.com/fastify/example/blob/HEAD/validation-messages/custom-errors-messages.js#L22) and its [test](https://github.com/fastify/example/blob/86775bf60f16a5b1a10be79ce30dfee87626d427/validation-messages/custom-errors-messages.test.js#L25).